# Как получить прямой доступ к видеоадаптеру?

Tags: windows, delphi, графика

Как, не используя directdraw, получить прямой доступ к видеоадаптеру (ведь directdDraw это как-то делает)? Киньте ссылку или учебник. Может это API видеоадаптера, то тогда если у всех фирм видеоадаптеров api отличаются, то как directDraw может быть таким универсальным?

Comment: очередной вам минус))

Comment: почему? . .

Comment: > Хороший заголовок

> в виде вопроса, например: "Как спрашивать?";
> четкий, ясный, краткий;
> понятный и информативный.

Comment: Понял, спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- http://programmersforum.ru/showthread.php?t=1262
- [http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Шейдер](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A8%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80)

гугл решает​​​​​​​​​​​